# How do I format and convert C# code to HTML

Tags: asp.net, editor, content-management-system

I am using a CMS that has FCK editor. It doesn't have an option to enter a Code sample like the way Stack Overflow's has.

I think the easiest way to do it would be to use an external editor, convert into HTML and use the HTML in the CMS to edit content.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
@IAN - It doesnt seem to be working for me. I tried using the `<pre>` markup both in the HTML view and the WYSISWG view.
The link says that I need the include JS and css file:

```
<link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
```

Does the FCK editor already include this?

Answer (score 6):

Two favorites:

For on-demand conversion: http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/

For on-the-fly conversion on a web page using Javascript: http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: as of today, this is off-line.

Comment: I'll be happy to update links if anyone knows of modern substitutes.

Comment: I really like https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/syntax_highlight.html: It supports many languages and is based on CSS instead of in-line styles.

Answer (score 2):

Can you implement [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/) and use a syntax highlighter for you code?  This is what [StackOverflow uses](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/potential-markup-and-editing-choices/).

Comment: No, not really. Unfortunately, the CMS does not allow me to use my own editor

Answer (score 2):

For formatting I am a big fan of [Google Code Javascript code prettifier](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).

Essentially you could paste your code in the FCK editor and wrap it as follows:

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-cs">
 Code here
</pre>
```

The FCK editor should handle the html conversion "<" and ">" to `&lt; and &gt;` if you paste it in to the "WYSIWYG" portion (not the source view).

Answer (score 2):

Just a note to say that the Jean-Claude Manoli code (mentioned in another post) and has now been extended and built into an application which will convert entire C# solutions, projects and source code files into an interlinked HTML documentation tree.

The application, called [CoDocke](http://www.OfItselfSo.com/CoDocker/CoDocker.php), is free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Manoli](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/) he/it will format c#, VB, html, xml, t-sql with some basic syntax highlighting - works for me. Source is also available, so you can extend it if interested.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) on my site.